# How to fix palm rejection on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: touchpad, hp-touchpad

I have an HP Pavillion G6-1d73us and I could drag my palm across the trackpad, and the pointer would move as if I had used my finger.

---

There are also other minor issues like the button to turn off the touch pad does not work.[image]

---

A third issue is that the natural scrolling toggle in settings doesn't do anything.

EDIT: this issue was fixed by doing a clean install instead of an upgrade

---

I would like to know if there is a fix for either of these issues, or if I have to go someplace else to report them.